# Combination of BreezeJS client side and Breeze Java (Hibernate) server side that works

Tags: java, breeze

Has anyone had any luck using the latest breeze.java.server code from https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.java in conjunction with the latest client BreezeJS libraries?

From this post https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/7563522-which-libraries-for-java-on-github it would seem that the Json-UriBuilder branch should be used but it appears to be incompatible with the query parameters generated by the client side.

An example is the "where" clause generated by the client side is "$filter=propertyname eg value" but on the server side the EntityQuery is never looking for a "filter" parameter and even if it were it would not build a valid query because this is not valid JSON.

What is the recommended combbination of libraries and/or approach to solving the above issue?

Comment: Wanted to comment that we have worked around this by providing the valid JSON to the .where() function on the client side (i.e. where({clientId: 1}). This creates a query param that would be valid in the server side EntityQuery.

On the server side we parse the query params before trying to create the EntityQuery. If the param key is "$filter" we change it to "where" which is what the EntityQuery is expecting.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. If you see Steve Schmitt's answer, it resolved the issue and using the JSON Uri Builder version of the Breeze java server project (https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.java) is actually really convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different URI formats that the Breeze client can use to send queries to the server: OData and JSON.  OData is the default, so if you don't configure Breeze otherwise, that's what you will get.  The recent Java server code only understands the JSON format, so you need to configure your Breeze client to send JSON.  Do this before you create your `entityManager`:

```
breeze.core.config.initializeAdapterInstance("uriBuilder", "json");
```

Then you'll get the JSON format and have full query support.

Comment: Thank you very much that did it.

Comment: I just added a [note to the Getting Started documentation](http://breeze.github.io/doc-java-hib/getting-started.html#configuring-the-client) about this, since it was missing.  If it had been there before, would you have noticed it?  Or is it too obscure?

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I apologize for the delayed reply. To be honest, I think I would have noticed but we were using an older branch of the java server side code on  previous project and updated it on this one. So, I am sure no one looked back at the getting started info this time.